# how to send scheduled sms via curl in php

Tags: php, curl, sms

I had been using curl for sending sms,but when scheduled sms is the need the curl was not working

```html
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
$phone='0000000000';
$msg="iam groot";
$time='08-01-2017 06:45';
$x="/username/password/senderid/".$phone."/".$msg."/".$time."/T";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://easyhops.co.in/sendsch/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$x);
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

the main problem shown was 'Invalid username or password';but when i used header the sms  was scheduled, and there were no errors.What was the mistake in my code?

Comment: if the API is complaining about your credentials you need to check with the API provider

Comment: is that really how to specify username/password? its a shitty scheme in which password can not contain an `/`, so i hope not, but where is the api documented?